# Pyspark compatibility with python 2.7

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, compatibility

Python 2.7, PySpark 2.4.6, spark version 3.3.0 Scala version 2.12.15, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_342. I am getting following error while running with python 2.7, although works fine for python 3.8

```
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/__init__.py", line 71
    def since(version: Union[str, float]) -> Callable[[F], F]:
                     ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Python 2 is dead. Use Python 3.7+!

Comment: How are you running two different Spark versions? 3.3.0 is not compatible with Python 2.7.

Comment: I really need to run old projects that are using python 2.7. Also, I need to run spark scripts and I came to know that I had to use spark 2.4.8 in order to use python 2.7.